# Angular 2 - Get passed object to component via inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

On my parent page I have a link here:

```
<a (click)="showPermissionsRates(5757);">Link</a>
```

The function sets it:

```
showPermissionsRates(item) {
        this.currentEventPoolId = item;
    }
```

With a child component on the parent page here:

```
<app-event-pools-permissions-rates [eventPoolId]="currentEventPoolId "></app-event-pools-permissions-rates>
```

And then in my child component TS file I use:

```
inputs: ['eventPoolId']
```

But how do I get that value of '5757' in the child component? Such as using alert?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking. What does `showPermissionRates()` do? Perhaps you could create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview) working example of what you've tried?

Comment: @Askanison4 I've just updated it :)

Comment: In short I wish to pass that '5757' value to be used in the child component TS file.

Comment: Can you show the `component.ts` for `app-event-pools-permission-rates`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use @Input() on the child property.

I've put this together showing a VERY basic example, but without more to go on regarding your issues, it's hard to know what you need:
https://plnkr.co/edit/y9clOla1WrPFmhMJoz7o?p=preview

The gist is to use `@Input()` to mark your inputs in the child component, and map those in the template of the parent.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import { ChildComponent } from 'child.component.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="changeProperty('ABC 123')">Click Me!</button>
    
      <child-component [childProperty]="parentProperty"></child-component>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  public parentProperty: string = "parentProp";
  
  public changeProperty(newProperty: string) : void {
    this.parentProperty = newProperty;
  }
}
```

Then, in the child:

```js
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
    <div>Hello World: {{ childProperty }}</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  
  @Input()
  childProperty:string;
  
  constructor() {
    this.childProperty = 'childProp'
  }
}
```

Comment: Nearly there, I would like to alert the 'ABC 123' value in the child TS file not in the template :)

Comment: Do you need to perform some action when the changes occur, or on a button click to view them?

Comment: Button click :)

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward just add a `(click)` handler to the child component. [See this updated Plunker for an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/y9clOla1WrPFmhMJoz7o?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect thanks that's great! I was getting confused with why I had [inputs] in the @component part at the top vs using @Input()

Comment: `inputs:[]` has much the same effect as `@Input()` - I just find it easier to annotate and decorate the code... easier for the next dev to follow what you were doing IMO :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting value to at input variable in a click event, then you have to listen for it in the child component constructor using ngonchanges

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

            if(changes['eventpoolid'] && changes['eventpoolid'].currentValue) {
// you get updated value here
    }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that sounds right. I'm not sure how I pull in that value from inputs: ['eventPoolId'] though. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated my answer, is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Why do you need to use `ngOnChanges`? Change detection is done automatically, no?

Comment: Hmm my question is simpler. I just need the value of "eventPoolId"

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward see my example above - it's very simple. No need to over-complicate if you can help it :)

Comment: If you need you do something when the value has changed,you can use ngonchanges otherwise @Input would do.

Comment: @RemyaJ Ah I get you. Good idea :) I didn't think the OP was asking about change tracking but that's a good tip